# Clarification of labeling of Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

I read a labeling of Lorentz matrix labeling $\Lambda^\mu_\nu$. To be more specific, it's used as $x^\mu\rightarrow \Lambda^\mu_\nu x^\nu$.
I want to ask:

1. What does the indices $\mu$, $\nu$ mean in $\Lambda^\mu_\nu$?
2. What does $x^\mu\rightarrow \Lambda^\mu_\nu x^\nu$ mean? Are $x^\mu$ and $x^\nu$ in the same frame?

Answer (score 1):

1. Τhe indices $\,\mu,\nu\,$ take the values $\,0,1,2,3$. The value $\,0\,$ corresponds to the time coordinate $x^0=c\,t\,$ while the values $\,1,2,3\,$ correspond to the space coordinates $\:\:x^1=\mathrm x,\:\:\:x^2=\mathrm y\:$ and $x^3=\mathrm z$.
2. Equation $\,x^\mu\rightarrow \Lambda^\mu_\nu x^\nu\,$ is better to expressed as $\,x'^\mu=\Lambda^\mu_\nu x^\nu\,$ and is the Lorentz transformation of the space-time position 4-vector from an inertial frame $\,\rm S\,$ to another inertial frame $\,\rm S'\,$ moving with constant velocity 3-vector with respect to the unprimed one.

Comment: So $\mu ,\nu$ in $\Lambda^\mu _\nu$ doesn't label matrix elements, but the whole matrix, right?

Comment: So $\mu ,\nu$ **DO label** matrix elements.  The whole matrix could  be expressed by $\Lambda$ without indices. $$\mathbf X'=\Lambda \mathbf X$$

Comment: Got it. Thanks!! By the way, do you have any recommended resources for learning QFT? That would be of much help!!

Comment: Take a look here [Book recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations).